# How to make display:grid inner long text div fit grid item size

Tags: html, css

Following is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
      width: 300px;
      border: solid 5px grey;
      gap: 10px;
      /* Optional: Add some gap between grid items */
    }
    
    .grid-item {
      /* Optional styling for the grid items */
      border: 1px solid #000;
      padding: 10px;
      /* Set a specific width for the grid items */
      width: 100%;
      /* Adjust this value based on your preference */
      /* Optional: Add styles for better visibility */
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .long-text {
      /* Make the text overflow ellipsis and hide overflow */
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Grid Example</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="long-text">car 1, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
        irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add more grid items as needed -->
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I set grid item width 100% and div width 100%, the div size still overflow grid border

Comment: Have you tried giving `overflow: hidden` to the `.grid-item`?

Answer (score 0):

@Hao Wu's answer is correct, I add overflow:hidden to grid-item it work

following is correct code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
      width: 300px;
      border: solid 5px grey;
      gap: 10px; /* Optional: Add some gap between grid items */
    }

    .grid-item {
      /* Optional styling for the grid items */
      border: 1px solid #000;
      padding: 10px;
      /* Set a specific width for the grid items */
      width: 100%; /* Adjust this value based on your preference */
      /* Optional: Add styles for better visibility */
      display: flex;
      overflow: hidden;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    .long-text {
      /* Set a maximum height for the text */
      /*max-height: 100px; !* Adjust this value based on your preference *!*/
      /* Make the text overflow ellipsis and hide overflow */
      width: 100%;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Grid Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="long-text">car 1, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do eiusmod tempor
      incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
      nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add more grid items as needed -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```